Unable to read multipart stream with Apache httpupload
I'm trying to read a sequence of image frames from a webcam's MJPEG stream using this code, mostly following the example usage javadoc at the top of MultipartStream:
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) new URL("http://....").openConnection();
            conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
            conn.connect();
            if (conn.getResponseCode() != 200)
                throw new RuntimeException("Failed to connect: " + conn.getResponseCode());

            String ct = conn.getHeaderField("Content-Type");
            String bnd = "--" + ct.split("boundary=")[1];
            System.out.println("Boundary is: " + bnd);

            try (InputStream is = conn.getInputStream()) {
                MultipartStream multi = new MultipartStream(is, bnd.getBytes(StandardCharsets.ISO_8859_1), 4096, null);
                boolean next = multi.skipPreamble(); // STUCK HERE
                while (next) {
                    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                    multi.readBodyData(baos);
                    processFrame(baos);
                    next = multi.readBoundary();
                }
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

Chrome seems able to render the stream successfully so I don't believe it's an invalid stream.  It gets stuck at multi.skipPreamble().  Internally it's just consuming the source InputStream endlessly without ever finding a boundary, I think.  Not sure what I'm doing wrong.  I've tried dumping the incoming stream to a file and looking at that but it looks ok to my untrained eye:

and then at the end of the first frame I can see this:

This repeats, as expected.

Another 200 ok (+4 headers) in the middle of a multipart is not normal for mutipart. That webcam is acting more like a http response pipeline.
The skipPreamble() intent should skip over those headers and not detect "--myboundary" because missing the "--".
Yet, the source of MultipartStream seems to momentarily ignore the needed "--". I think you found a weakness exposed from not so legal data. Not sure they would fix it.
See https://github.com/apache/tomcat/blob/main/java/org/apache/tomcat/util/http/fileupload/MultipartStream.java#L609.
You should try stepping into this code to see if it mistakenly pickup the repeated boundary=myboundary from the unexpectedly repeated 4 headers.

i did wonder about the repeated headers, but considered it might just have been my poor understanding.  do you mean you think the -2 offset intended to allow a missing CRLF is caused it to miss the -- ?  i'll try to have a deeper dig into the MultipartStream code and see what's going on, was hoping to avoid it...

This is where I'm torn between having a life, and satisfying my curiosity. If I had all the code ready and running like you, I would not hesitate a second to debug step into and watch the code. Right now for me it's too much asked to either set it up (and I have no such web cam) or really put my brain into analysis mode. So, just debug it, it'll take 2 minutes.

I did a stupid thing: MultipartStream expects the boundary to be specified without -- on the front.  Now everything behaves correctly.

debugging is great!
